# How to create a stroke around a custom mask?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uibezierpath, stroke

I'm trying to create a border around a mask using a UIimage. When I create the mask in code it looks fine:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageToBeMasked: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let mask = UIImageView(image: Image)
    imageToBeMasked.mask = mask
}
```

[image: mask]

But when I try and create a stroke around it appears to not use the mask at all:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var imageToBeMasked: UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let mask = UIImageView(image: Image)

    // the layer used to mask the image view
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: mask.bounds).cgPath
    imageToBeMasked.layer.mask = maskLayer

    // the layer used to draw the border
    let strokeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    strokeLayer.frame = imageToBeMasked.bounds
    strokeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    strokeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: mask.bounds).cgPath
    strokeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    strokeLayer.lineWidth = 4
    imageToBeMasked.layer.addSublayer(strokeLayer)
}
```

[image: stroke]

Any clue on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `CALayer` is not affected by the mask itself. The quickest way would be creating a new image which is slightly bigger than the original, place it behind the original image and tint it with a color.

```
let templateImage = originalImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
strokeImageView.image = templateImage
strokeImageView.tintColor = .black
```

Comment: Ok, but I plan on animating the mask

Comment: Whoops I meant I plan on animating the stroke